# Two column drag-and-drop in Flutter

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop

I'm making a drag-and-drop feature with Flutter where users drag values between two columns. I created two DragTarget, one for each column, and lists to keep track of the data for each column. When a Draggable is accepted, I add it to the list, and for onLeave, I remove it from the list. However, there is a duplication issue where the draggable appears both in the column it just left and the new column it was accepted into. I'm thinking this may be due to only one of the DragTargets updating at once, but it seems like that shouldn't happen. Any ideas on how to design and handle the data here?

Comment: Can you please share the code and maybe some screenshots? Does the duplicate only remain on screen while you're dragging? Or only before that/after that/all the time?